# AWS Athena mis-reading date formats

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, datetime, amazon-athena

I'm trying to upload a pandas dataframe to an S3 bucket, and then query it using Athena. 
I've uploaded the datetimes in the following format:

```
pd.to_datetime(df["myDateTime"], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
2019-08-07 08:04:43.942000+00:00

df.dtypes
myDateTime datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

When I try and query the result in Athena I end up with this:

```
+51568-02-09 14:52:22.000
```

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS default.dashboardtable(
  `myDateTime` timestamp,
```

I've tried changing the date format in Pandas to exclude microseconds but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Are you sure that is the same record?  Input to output?

Comment: Yep it is the same record

Comment: @davo777 it seems your question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56430840/how-to-handle-timestamp-micros-parquet-fields-in-presto-athena . I guess you're using Parquet, correct?

Comment: The way I solved it was converting my datetime columns back to strings, removing this bit "000+00:00", and changing the format to timestamps once in Athena

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're building Athena tables on parquet files in S3. Which means you're probably using the `to_parquet()` method to export the dataframes to parquet files.

If you're using the pyarrow engine, you can pass a `coerce_timestamps` kwarg to `to_parquet()` which will reduce the precision of the datetimes from ns down to ms (or some other unit that doesn't conflict with Athena/presto.

So you're to_parquet method should look something like this

```
df.to_parquet(parquet_path, engine='pyarrow', coerce_timestamps='ms')
```

This solution does not work with other parquet engines like `fastparquet`.

Also, I owe a lot credit to [@tipanverella's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63194941/athena-returns-wrong-values-for-timestamp-fields-in-parquet-files)

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem. I ended up dividing the resulting integer by 1000 and using the `from_unixtime` function when querying.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is related but in the [json2parquet](https://pypi.org/project/json2parquet/) docs they mention

"If you are using this library to convert JSON data to be read by Spark, Athena, Spectrum or Presto make sure you use use_deprecated_int96_timestamps when writing your Parquet files, otherwise you will see some really screwy dates."

Maybe check your date format wherever you're transforming your data into parquet?