# Athena returns wrong values for timestamp fields in parquet files

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, parquet, amazon-athena

I am mostly reproducing here an issue that I have seen raised on [forum.aws](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=934595) in hopes that the answers/explanations of the stackoverflow community are more thorough, and illuminating than the discussion on the forum.

Here is my experience of the issue:
I make a parquet files from a dataframe in python using pandas, and cast a field/column say birthday as a `datetime64[ns]` using `pandas.to_datetime`.  This part of the process seems flawless as I can read the parquet files using `pandas.read_parquet` and get what I expect, namely the dates entered in datetime.
However, when I load said parquet file to AWS and put a `athena` table on it, reading the same birthday column yields junk dates that in no way match the ones in the parquet file.  For example:

```py
t = pandas.DataFrame([['Haiti',pandas.to_datetime('1804-01-01')]],columns=['Country','Independence'])
t.to_parquet("s3://<mybucket>/tmp/t.parquet")
```

```
|Country | Independence|
|--------|-------------|
|Haiti   | 1804-01-01  |
```

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS default.mytable (
  `Country` string,
  `Independence` timestamp 
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = '1'
) LOCATION 's3://<mybucket>/tmp/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');

SELECT * FROM "default"."mytable" limit 10;
```

```
|Country | Independence             |
|--------|--------------------------|
|Haiti   |-164033-12-18 00:00:00.000|
```

Comment: This is Parquet value being stored as microseconds, but being interpreted as milliseconds, and thus a wrong value is returned. You should report this to AWS support. Also, since Athena is based on Presto, you can file an issue https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/new as well.

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen, thank you.  I posted the [issue](https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/4662).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can force to_parquet to write in a format Athena will understand with "coerce_timestamps":

```py
t = pandas.DataFrame([['Haiti',pandas.to_datetime('1804-01-01')]],columns=['Country','Independence'])
t.to_parquet("s3://<mybucket>/tmp/t.parquet", coerce_timestamps='ms')
```

```
|Country | Independence|
|--------|-------------|
|Haiti   | 1804-01-01  |
```

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS default.mytable (
  `Country` string,
  `Independence` timestamp 
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = '1'
) LOCATION 's3://<mybucket>/tmp/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');

SELECT * FROM "default"."mytable" limit 10;
```

```
|Country | Independence          |
|--------|-----------------------|
|Haiti   |1804-01-01 00:00:00.000|
```

Comment: This does not work pandas 1.1.4 + fastparquet 0.4.1: Error in  pandas/io/parquet.py, function write()" `TypeError: write() got an unexpected keyword argument 'coerce_timestamps'`

Comment: I am using pyarrow, to enable pandas to read/write parquet

Comment: I guess the kwarg `coerce_timestamps` is handled bt pyarrow but not fastparquet then.

Comment: Would you be able to try the solution with pyarrow?

Comment: I found a solution using fastparquet. I passed the kwarg times=“int96” to df.to_parquet() and that yielded a parquet file with int96 datetime format. The datetimes in Athena now correspond to what I put in from pandas.